# C++11 substitute for `GetExitCodeThread` to monitor thread status?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I'm working on a large refactoring and port of a existing application that does some pretty spectacular(ly horrible) things with windows threads.

Right now, there is internal logic that calls `GetExitCodeThread(m_threadHandle, &exitCode);` on a set of running threads, and then checks  if `exitCode == STILL_ACTIVE` to determine if the thread in question is still executing, or has returned, and then uses that to sequence some internal logic.

How can I check if a `std::thread` is still executing, or has returned/thrown an exception?

I know about `std::async`, `std::promises` and `std::future`. However, using those would involve considerable refactoring, and I don't feel I know the code-base well enough to make that scale of changes without breaking a dozen other things.

Comment: You can't really check if a [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) object has finished or not, not without using platform-specific functions. [`std::asynch`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/async) is probably the way to go for your use-case.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg - That's what I'm afraid of. The whole application is kind of ridiculously enormous and complicated, and does a whole pile of things with internal synchronization, and I think if I touch anything, the whole thing will just explode.

Comment: I only need to target two platforms (windows, linux), so I'm considering just  doing a single platform specific thing per-platform.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're going to replace the direct calls to the Windows thread API with std::thread anyway, then a good option would be to write a class derived from std::thread and use it instead. In the constructor, you encapsulate the passed functor in your own functor, which sets a thread-safe flag 'running' to true, calls the other functor, and sets the flag back to false. Then you simply need a method is_running() to return the contents of this flag.

Comment: Yeah, this is the direction I'm leaning. This is the first C++ thing I've really worked on, so it's a bit overwhelming for the moment.

Comment: This was the solution I wound up using.

Answer (score 1):

On Windows, thread objects become signaled upon exit.

Therefore, calling `WaitForSingleObject()` on a valid thread handle (in your case, you'd obtain this via `std::thread::native_handle()` )with a timeout value of 0 will return `WAIT_TIMEOUT`, indicating that the thread is indeed still active.

Comment: Yeah, I'm actually working on porting from windows -> linux. It uses `GetExitCodeThread(m_threadHandle, &exitCode);`, which returns `STILL_ACTIVE` if the thread is alive. That still leaves a linux solution, though.

Comment: Got it - Unfortunately there's no canned equivalent on Linux/POSIX that'll duplicate that functionality.  You'll have to roll something yourself.  If you're using std::thread objects, you could wrap your thread functions in a class with a condition variable that you can signal when the wrapped function returns.  Good luck!